# How to reproduce this fixed background header effect in react-native

Tags: react-native, mobile, scroll, expo, react-navigation

i'm having big issues trying to reproduce [this simple effect](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/discussions/11656) in react-native.

I aim to reproduce the behavior where i have a "fixed background" header that gets covered by the content when the user scrolls.

I tried both position and absolute positionning but my header keeps getting pushed to the top.

Is it possible to achieve this simply with or without an external library ? Thank you.

[requested behavior to reproduce example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xxay.gif)

Comment: You may need to make your header part of the screen instead of passing it through react navigation